# Where to initialize static values, used by various fragments?

Tags: kotlin, resources, viewmodel

I will try to describe my question as simple as i can.

For example i have 10 strings stored in resources.

But in my code i have too many calls upon this strings, thus, to make my code more readable, i want to avoid using direct access to them: `resources.getString(R.string.nameOne)` or `resources.getStringArray(R.array.names)`

Instead, i want to initialize them as values in one place, from which i will be able to retrieve them whenever i need to.

I tried to store them in ViewModel, however since ViewModel has no direct access to app context, i did this:

```
lateinit var nameOne: String
lateinit var nameTwo: String
lateinit var nameThree: String
...
lateinit var nameTen: String

fun initializeNames(list: Array<String>) {
nameOne = list[0]
nameTwo = list[1]
nameThree = list[2]
...
nameTen = list[9]
}
```

Basically i call this method once when i need to, and put array of names directly from resources. After that i use these values in any fragment i want.

Is this approach good? Or should i create a separate class for this matter? I am trying to avoid AndroidViewModel since this considered as bad practice.

Comment: What platform/framework is this to work with?  Spring?  Android?  JavaFX?  Ktor?  Or is this a ‘raw’ program that uses only the Kotlin runtime?

Comment: I'm assuming Android because of the mention of AndroidViewModel and `R.string...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't cache String resources in a ViewModel, because the ViewModel survives configuration changes, but String resources should not because the configuration change could be a change to locale or language.

I think the simplest thing to do would be to use a lazy delegate in your Activity or Fragment:

```
val myStrings by lazy { resources.get(R.array.myStrings) }
```

This will fetch the Strings from disk the first time it's accessed, but will use the cached copy in memory on each subsequent access. If the Activity or Fragment is recreated due to configuration change, it will be a new instance, so it will freshly fetch them from disk again.

If it's used in various Fragments, I'd put this property in the Activity.

I use a single Activity, so I consider it safe to create an extension property for my Fragments to access the Activity's unique properties, like this:

```
val Fragment.myActivity: MyActivity
    get() = requireActivity() as MyActivity
```

Comment: This is my first acquaintance with extensions, i think i understood overall idea. Recommendation successfully implemented, thank you once again for the big help :)